# Как работает рекурсия в JAVA?

Tags: java, рекурсия

Есть небольшой код

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(drive(4, 6));
    }
    public static int drive(int a, int b) {

        if (a == 0) return Math.abs(a - b);

        return Math.min(
                        drive(a - 1, b + 1),
                        drive(a - 1, b + 1)
        );
    }
}
```

Вопрос: почему когда "a" становится 0, не происходит выход из метода, а наоборот "a" становится 1, потом 2,
потом снова 1 и так ещё несколько итераций.

Целый вечер сижу никак не могу разобраться как это работает. В дебаг режиме запускал код, и всё равно не понял откуда берутся значения "a" после того, как она опускается к 0.

Спасибо!

Comment: `почему когда "a" становится 0, не происходит выход из метода, а наоборот "a" становится 1, потом 2, потом снова 1 и так ещё несколько итераций` - выход из метода происходит тут `if (a == 0) return Math.abs(a - b);`

Comment: вы видимо не очень понимаете, что такое стек вызовов функции. Попробуйте на бумажке нарисовать, сколько раз вызывается функция и какое значение каждый вызов возвращает.

Comment: Рекурсия в джаве работает так же, как и в почти всех других языках.

Comment: @tym32167 раньше думал, что понимаю, теперь понимаю, что не очень :) Я думал, что после того, как А становится 0, тогда и будет выходит. Но спасибо, что натолкнули на мысль: пойду гуглить про стэк и рекурсию

Comment: Реурсия как матрешка. Первый вызов - самая большая матрешка, второй - матрешка поменьше, третий - ещё меньше. Самая малкая матрешка заканчивается на `f (a == 0) return Math.abs(a - b);`, но результат работы она передает предыдущей матрешке, та своей предыдущей и т.д. до самой большой матрешки.

Answer (score 1):

Eсли немного поменять код то можно увидеть сколько раз будет вызывается рекурсия

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(drive(4, 6));
    }
    public static int drive(int a, int b) {
        System.out.printf("\n(a = %d b = %d)", a, b);
        if (a == 0) return Math.abs(a - b);

        return Math.min(
                        drive(a - 1, b + 1),
                        drive(a - 1, b + 1)
        );
    }
}
```

вывод такой

```
(a = 4 b = 6)
(a = 3 b = 7)
(a = 2 b = 8)
(a = 1 b = 9)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 1 b = 9)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 2 b = 8)
(a = 1 b = 9)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 1 b = 9)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 3 b = 7)
(a = 2 b = 8)
(a = 1 b = 9)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 1 b = 9)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 2 b = 8)
(a = 1 b = 9)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 1 b = 9)
(a = 0 b = 10)
(a = 0 b = 10)10
```

Answer (score 1):

Вас путает то что в функции `drive` два рекурсивных вызова. Я нарисую дерево вызовов, а вы проверите в отладчике, что значения `a` и `b` меняются именно в таком порядке:

```
drive(4, 6)
    drive(3, 7)
        drive(2, 8)
            drive(1, 9)
                drive(0, 10)
                drive(0, 10)
            drive(1, 9)
                drive(0, 10)
                drive(0, 10)
        drive(2, 8)
            drive(1, 9)
                drive(0, 10)
                drive(0, 10)
            drive(1, 9)
                drive(0, 10)
                drive(0, 10)
    drive(3, 7)
        drive(2, 8)
            drive(1, 9)
                drive(0, 10)
                drive(0, 10)
            drive(1, 9)
                drive(0, 10)
                drive(0, 10)
        drive(2, 8)
            drive(1, 9)
                drive(0, 10)
                drive(0, 10)
            drive(1, 9)
                drive(0, 10)
                drive(0, 10)
```

Если вы в отладчике поставить точку останова в начале функции, то получите такую последовательность значений `a`:

```
4 3 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 3 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

Посмотрите стек вызовов. В нём значения `a` будут выглядеть так:

```
4
4 3
4 3 2
4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2
4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3
4 3 2
4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2
4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0
```